# Pass large amount of binary data from u-boot to linux kernel

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

Have some issues with passing large amount of data (3 MB) from uboot to linux kernel 2.6.35.3 on imx50 ARM board. This data is required in kernel device driver probe function and then it should be released. First uboot load data from flash to RAM, then pass physical address for linux kernel using bootargs. In kernel I try to reserve certain amount of memory using reserve_resource() in arch/arm/kernel/setup.c file:

```
--- a/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c   Tue Jul 17 11:22:39 2012 +0300
+++ b/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c   Fri Jul 20 14:17:16 2012 +0300

struct resource my_mem_res = {
    .name = "My_Region",
    .start = 0x77c00000,
    .end = 0x77ffffff,
    .flags = IORESOURCE_MEM | IORESOURCE_BUSY,
};

@@ -477,6 +479,10 @@
    kernel_code.end     = virt_to_phys(_etext - 1);
    kernel_data.start   = virt_to_phys(_data);
    kernel_data.end     = virt_to_phys(_end - 1);
+   my_mem_res.start    = mi->bank[i].start + mi->bank[i].size - 0x400000;
+   my_mem_res.end      = mi->bank[i].start + mi->bank[i].size - 1;

    for (i = 0; i < mi->nr_banks; i++) {
        if (mi->bank[i].size == 0)
@@ -496,6 +502,8 @@
        if (kernel_data.start >= res->start &&
            kernel_data.end <= res->end)
            request_resource(res, &kernel_data);
+
+       request_resource(res, &my_mem_res);
    }

    if (mdesc->video_start) {
```

By this I'm trying to tell kernel that this memory area it reserved and this data should not be modified by kernel.

```
70000000-77ffffff : System RAM
  70027000-7056ffff : Kernel text
  70588000-7062094f : Kernel data
  77c00000-77ffffff : My_Region
```

In driver `ioremap(0x77c00000, AREA_SIZE)` is used to get kernel memory address. But when I dump content of memory, there is only zeros. If boot kernel with `mem=120M` (total 128MB RAM is avaliable), then my data is above kernel system ram region, then I get data I expect.

So, my questions:

Why I get zeros and how do I pass large amount of binary data from uboot to linux kernel?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with the ARM ... but take a look at boot/compressed/head.S. In short, when Linux boots it clears the RAM. It's a bit complex, since u-boot prepares the actual memory size before Linux kernel bootup. Look up bootm.c do_bootm_linux() there is a call there setup_memory_tags(). These are old but the gist is still valid [1](http://www.simtec.co.uk/products/SWLINUX/files/booting_article.html) and [2](http://amitshah.bizhat.com/arm/arm_linux_boot-1.html). HTH

Comment: Make sure that your bootloader isn't doing a memtest before starting the boot sequence. That could explain why you are seeing zeros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a custom *ATAG* to either pass the data block or to pass the address & length of the data.  Note that the "A" in *ATAG* stands for ARM, so this solution is not portable to other architectures.  An *ATAG* is preferable to a command-line *bootarg* IMO because you do not want the user to muck with physical memory addresses.  Also the Linux kernel will process the *ATAG* list before the MMU (i.e. virtual memory) is enabled.

In U-Boot, look at `lib_arm/armlinux.c` or `arch/arm/lib/bootm.c` for routines that build the ARM tag list.  Write your own routine for your new tag(s), and then invoke it in *do_bootm_linux()*.

In the Linux kernel *ATAGs* are processed in `arch/arm/kernel/setup.c`, when virtual memory has not yet been enabled.  If you just pass an address & length values from U-Boot, then the pointer & length can be assigned to global variables that are exported,

```
void          *my_data;
unsigned int  my_dlen;
EXPORT_SYMBOL(my_data);
EXPORT_SYMBOL(my_dlen);
```

and then the driver can retrieve it.

```
extern void          *my_data;
extern unsigned int  my_dlen;

request_mem_region(my_data, my_dlen, DRV_NAME);
md_map = ioremap(my_data, my_dlen);
```

I've used similar code to probe for SRAM in U-Boot, then pass the starting address & number of KBytes found to the kernel in a custom *ATAG*.  A kernel driver obtains these values, and if they are nonzero and have sane values, creates a block device out of the SRAM.  The major difference from your situation is that the SRAM is in a completely different physical address range from the SDRAM.

**NOTE**
An *ATAG* is built by U-Boot for the physical memory that the kernel can use, so this is really where you need to define and exclude your reserved RAM.  It's probably too late to do that in the kernel.